# Trying to use npm with .net core to use i.e. Bootstrap

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build an aspnetcore mvc-app from a console-app and I'm no comfortable with implementing the Program.cs and Startup.cs classes, adding the controller, action and view.

So now I'm ready to start working with frontend and I thought that I should learn a good package-manager and workflow to add front-end packages to `wwwroot/lib`. As I've understood it npm (and webpack) are highly recommended for this (unless I'm mistaken).

I have a hard time finding a tutorial teaching me how to do this though, most of them introduce several concepts (Angular, Typescript, Yeoman Gulp, etc.) that confuse me as to whether I'm learning what I'm looking for.

I asked [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/6prk2i/how_to_add_npm_to_a_net_core_project_vscode_on/) and thought I'd start with a workflow rughly like this:

1. Run `npm init` in my project folder (adding a `node_modules` folder to the project)
2. Run `npm install bootstrap --save`. This will install the NPM module in a `node_module` folder.
3. Manually copy the bootstrap-module from my `node_module` to `wwwroot/lib` through the cp command.

Now this doesn't feel right or "correct" I'd love to look into WebPack which was suggested in my previous question as a way to do *bundling* (which I must admit I haven't learned yet) for step three.

So my general question would be if this seem to be a reasonable approach to start out with or if it's seriously flawed compared to how it's supposed to be done?

A specific question is what is the npm entry point? The default is Index.js but is this right for a dotnet mvc-app? As you might notice I'm a bit confused as to where to look for answers for my problem so hope if there's no good answer you might be able to point me in the right direction? :)

---

EDIT: PS, Using Visual Studio Code (my computer can't handle Visual Studio) so can't use tools unique for VS.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Comment: hey @MrJalapeno - good to see you are using .NET Core :) Is your problem that you are confused on what package manager to use for front end dotnet Core dev?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Yes that's exactly my problem :) It seems that everywhere I look people are saying that Bower is dead so I'm looking at npm right now. 

Right now I'm looking at ways to move my front-end packages from `node_modules` to `wwwroot/lib` (which has me looking at a tutorial on gulp).

Any tips, help or ideas are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out, I'm having the same issue.